# Multiplying lists of matrices without loops

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Hi everyone and thank you for your assistance. I am new to python and failed to find an efficient alternative to for loops for the following task.

I want to multiply ndarrays `A` and `B` of dimension `(d,n,m)` and `(d,m)`, respectively. With some abuse of terminology to help understanding, `A` is a list of `nxm` matrices and `B` is a list of vectors in `R^m`.

For example:

```
A = np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]],[[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]])
B = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]])
```

My solution uses a for loop

```
for i in range(2):
    print(A[i]*B[i])
```

Is there any cheaper alternative (no loops)?

Thank you again

Comment: It might be helpful to question why you are doing this, most (if not all) answers are going to have another loop under the hood somewhere, just further obscured. What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @Laif I think the point is to use `numpy` methods, where the loops are pushed down into the C layer, not at the interpreter level.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's precisely true. I cannot avoid that situation to arise, so just need the most efficient way to deal with it (i.e. bring the loop at the C level)

Comment: `np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', A, B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use broadcasting by adding in a new dimension in the "middle" for `B`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]],[[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]])
>>> B = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]])
>>> A * B[:, None, :]
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]],

       [[15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
        [20, 24, 28, 32, 36],
        [25, 30, 35, 40, 45]]])
```

[Here is a link to the official docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Note, your original solution already relied on broadcasting:

```
>>> A[0]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> B[0]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> A[0] * B[0]
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
```